# How to extend a class with additional params

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am consuming a web API that has a model.  `eRating.PlanRate`.  I need to add some properties to that for my custom application.

I tried `public partial class eRating.PlanRate` but this would not seem to work.  Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: You can create a new class that inherits from `PlanRate` but if `PlanRate` is not defined as `sealed`.

Comment: Thanks @S.Akbari Seems to be working will run it through some tests.

Comment: @S.Akbari Yeah might as well for others benefit at least.  I'm already running through some tests with it hoping it will work till the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new class that inherits from `PlanRate` but if `PlanRate` is not defined as [`sealed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) already, because the `sealed` when applied to a class, it prevents other classes from inheriting from it.

```
public class yourClass : PlanRate
{
    public string yourProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Also as an another approach you can add a method to the base class by using [`Extension Methods`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) but just for methods not properties because *extension properties* do not exist.

Comment: Well, Extension properties do exist, but only for WPF. They go by the name of "Attached Properties".